# Advanced Android Animation - Scale: Moving near by Views

Tags: java, android, animation, scale

I am able to scale Views using standard animation procedures.

```
Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 2.0F);
    anim.setFillAfter(true);
    anim.setDuration(animationLength);
    anim.setInterpolator(this, android.R.anim.linear_interpolator);
    view.setAnimation(anim);
        view.startLayoutAnimation();
```

view is a ViewAnimator but the type shouldn't really matter.

The entire view is contained within a LinearLayout.

So as I scale up the view as above, I am expecting the views bellow the image (buttons, text etc) to move down and be shown below the scaled up image. This is not happening, the end result is that the view is twice as large, but the buttons do not move, and are shown on top (rendered over, not linearly on top) my scaled up view.

Now, I could go about transforming the rest of the view but this seems inefficient, so is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks Aiden

Comment: You can try changing the width and height (`LayoutParams`) of the view - combined with android:animateLayoutChanges on the container, but this won't work prior to Honeycomb.

Comment: This seems to be the best way I can see, however i need to support back to 2.2. http://nineoldandroids.com/ Is the backwards compatible animation however LayoutTransitions are not supported.

Comment: Alternatively you can continuously change the LayoutParams of the view, although I'm not sure how this will perform.